# How to delete Text file by what it contains

Tags: python, filtering

I want to remove text files from my directory. I build a webscraper but because i dont know how to make my code that it sees what its scraping i need to remove files that contains: "Dit vers is in de gekozen berijming niet beschikbaar. Kies hieronder een andere berijming."

This is my code

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


url = 'https://psalmboek.nl/zingen.php?psID='
psalm = int(1)
url3 = '&psvID='
vers = int(1)
url5 = '#psvs'

end_psalm = 151
end_vers = 89


while vers != end_vers or psalm != end_psalm:

    response = requests.get(url + str(psalm) + url3 + str(vers) + url5)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    soup.findAll('p')
    one_a_tag = soup.findAll('p')[0]
    f = open("psalm"+str(psalm)+"_"+"vers"+str(vers) +  ".txt","w+")
    f.write(re.sub(re.compile('<.*?>'), '', str(one_a_tag)))
    f.close
    vers += 1

    while vers == end_vers:
        psalm += 1
        vers -= end_vers
        vers += 1
        break

    while psalm == end_psalm:
        continue

    print (vers)

else:
    print("STOP")
```

When i run this program it will write for all 150 psalters 88 verses. While psalter 119 contains 88 verses. Pslater 1 contains just 4.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Solve **what exactly**?

Comment: i want my program to read by doing this i think '''f = open("psalm"+str(psalm)+"_"+"vers"+str(vers) +  ".txt","r")'''' and than read the first line . if the first line says: "Dit vers is in de gekozen berijming niet beschikbaar. Kies hieronder een andere berijming." remove the file

Comment: It seems that you need to check whether `one_a_tag` contains this text and if it does then skip everything else. Nothing needs to be deleted as such files will not be even created.

Comment: You are a hero :) thank you